# Unknown Solution item type Visual Studio for MAC

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

i got this error when try to open solution created from Windows - VS2019.
[image]

Comment: your link is for windows

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Comment: Make sure the Apple SDK is set correctly as mentioned in [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/225699/#Comment_225699) and have a look at [this thread](https://github.com/QuantConnect/Lean/issues/2724) may also help.

Comment: Show us the error message that you see.

Comment: @FilipePilettiPlucenio here https://github.com/brminnick/UITestSampleApp/issues/54

Answer (score -4):

I had the same issue and error message initially - *unknown solution item type*

I looked around for further logs/error but saw nothing obvious. I then right-clicked on the project and selected 'reload' and it loaded fine. Worth giving that a try.

Comment: This response provided no answer to the issue.